# My sql query is right or wrong ? It showing me error like Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

my query is

```
$statement = "SELECT * FROM profile_details
       WHERE    YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dob) BETWEEN '$search_age'
                                              AND '$search_age1'
            AND gender LIKE '$search_gender'
        OR main_caste LIKE '$search_relegion'
        OR education_type LIKE '$search_qualification'
        OR occupation LIKE '$search_occupation'";
```

When i echo `mysqli_error($con);` it's showing message

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
         to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
         to use near
     'SELECT * FROM profile_details
      WHERE YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dob) BETWEEN '20' AND '' at line 1
```

My connection file is given below

```
<?php

/*Default time zone ,to be able to send mail */
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

//connect database
$con = mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","root","testdb") or die ("Unable to connect. Check your connection parameters.");         //host, username, password, database name

        //database connect error
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {   
        echo "Failed to connect to MySql: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
        }

?>
```

And the search result php file is .. I am using pagination for search results... On this page i am getting error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM profile_details WHERE

```
    <?php 
                date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
                require_once("includes/config.php");
                require_once("includes/user_pagination.php");
                global $con;
                //if(isset($_POST['home_quick_search'])){

                //get serch data from index.php
                    $search_gender = $_GET['s_gender']; 
                    $search_relegion = $_GET['s_religion']; 
                    $search_occupation = $_GET['s_occupation']; 
                    $search_age = $_GET['s_age']; 
                    $search_age1 = $_GET['s_age1']; 
                    $search_qualification = $_GET['s_qualification']; 

                $page = (int)(!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
                if ($page <= 0) $page = 1;

                $per_page = 10; // Set how many records do you want to display per page.

                $startpoint = ($page * $per_page) - $per_page;

                $statement = "`profile_details` WHERE `DATEDIFF(YEAR,dob,CURDATE())` AS dob BETWEEN '$search_age' AND '$search_age1' AND `gender` LIKE '$search_gender' OR `main_caste` LIKE '$search_relegion' OR `education_type` LIKE '$search_qualification' OR `occupation` LIKE '$search_occupation' ORDER BY `user_id` ASC"; 

//$statement = "SELECT * FROM profile_details WHERE YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dob) BETWEEN '$search_age' AND '$search_age1' AND gender LIKE '$search_gender' AND main_caste LIKE '$search_relegion' AND education_type LIKE '$search_qualification' AND occupation LIKE '$search_occupation'";



                $results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page}") or die (mysqli_error($con));

                    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) != 0) {

                    // displaying records.
                    $i = 0; 
                        while ($row_user = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

                        $u_id = $row_user['user_id'];
                        $u_pid = $row_user['profile_id'];
                        $u_gender = $row_user['gender'];
                        $u_fname = $row_user['first_name'];
                        $u_relegion = $row_user['main_caste'];
                        $u_city = $row_user['city'];
                        $u_image = $row_user['photo'];
                        $u_dob = $row_user['dob'];

                        //age calculation
                        $dateOfBirth = $u_dob;
                        $today = date("Y-m-d");
                        $diff = date_diff(date_create($dateOfBirth), date_create($today));
                        //echo 'Age is '.$diff->format('%y');
                        $age = $diff->format('%y');
                        //age calculation ends

                        $u_status_all = $row_user['user_status'];
                        $u_status_of = $row_user['user_status']=='OFFLINE';
                        $u_status_on = $row_user['user_status']=='ONLINE';


                     echo'
                          <div class="col-sm-6 paid_people-left">
                            <ul class="profile_item">
                              <a href="view_profile.php?userdetail_id=$u_id">

                               <li class="profile_item-img">';

                              if (!empty($u_image)){
                                  echo '<img src="users-photo/resized_'.$u_image.'" class="img-responsive" alt="'.$u_fname.'"/>';
                              }
                              else{
                                  echo '<img src="images/s2.jpg" class="img-responsive"  alt=""/>';
                              }



                            echo ' </li>   
                                <li class="profile_item-desc">
                                  <h4>Profile ID: '.$u_pid.'</h4>
                                  <p>Age: '.$age.' Yrs, '.$u_gender.'</p>
                                  <h5>View Full Profile</h5>
                                  <p>';

    if (!isset($u_status_on) && $u_status_of){
                            echo "Nope";
                        }
                        elseif (isset ($u_status_of) && $u_status_on){
                            echo "<img src='images/online.png' /> <span class='label label-success'>"; 
                        }
                        else {  
                        if (isset ($u_status_of)){
                            echo "<img src='images/offline.png' /> <span class='label label-default'>"; 
                            }   
                        }

                        echo "
                            $u_status_all</span><p>
                            </li>
                            <div class='clearfix'> </div>
                            </a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>";                       

                    }

                    } else {
                                            echo "Sorry ! No Profiles are found.";
                                    }

            //  }   

            ?>

               <div class="pagination-div">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <?php echo pagination($statement,$per_page,$page,$url='?'); ?>
                </ul>
           </div>
```

Please help ..thanks in advance

Comment: well, do echo $statement and print out the result.

Comment: It's right there! Error in your syntax. Check your SQL query, it's obviously wrong.

Comment: @Dimi  thanks... I am trying to convert date of birth in age format ...how to convert it...

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dob,CURDATE()) AS age

Comment: @Dimi thanks... i tried above but its showing same error .... my `dob` type is `date` ........

Comment: Why is this tagged as SQL Server and MySQL when the error clearly says you are using MariaDB?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes:

The `AND` operator has a higher order of precedence than the `OR` operator. Adding parens can make your intent more clear to a future reader. Did you intend to check age only if the gender matched, and ignore the condition on age otherwise?

The calculation of age seems a bit strange, since it entirely ignores the month and day. The normative pattern is to compare the bare DATE column to expressions that return DATE values...

```
 WHERE ( t.dob >  DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 25 YEAR AND
         t.dob <= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 19 YEAR
       )
```

As a demonstration of the values returned by those expressions ...

```
SELECT DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 25 YEAR AS b 
     , DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 19 YEAR AS e
```

returns

```
b           e           
----------  ----------
1992-02-10  1998-02-10
```

For debugging a problem with the SQL, echo or var_dump the value of the SQL text, before submitting it for execution.

Then examine the SQL.

---

The code pattern shown in the question, including values in the SQL text, is a pattern we frequently see in code that is vulnerable to SQL Injection. We can't tell whether this code is vulnerable, because we can't tell whether those values have been properly escaped.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT ... ) AS x  -- You need parens around derived query

a AND b OR c
is treated as
( a AND b ) OR c
```

Please add parens to your boolean expression to convince us that you did it right.